# How to login users only with verified emails in json_login in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have [JWT authentication](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) in Symfony app. 
`security.yaml`

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        registration:
            pattern: account.register
            anonymous: true

        verification:
            pattern: account.verify
            anonymous: true

        login:
            pattern: account.login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: account.login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

I want to login users only with verified email. Now after registration, email is not verified yet, but user is already can login. I want to prevent it while `verified_at` is null in User entity.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Solution in decorator style.

`security.yaml`

```
login:
            pattern: account.login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: account.login
                #success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                success_handler: App\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

`App\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler`

```
<?php

namespace App\Security\Authentication;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler as BaseAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface $baseHandler;

    public function __construct(BaseAuthenticationSuccessHandler $baseHandler)
    {
        $this->baseHandler = $baseHandler;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if (!$token->getUser()->isVerified()) {
            return new JsonResponse('Not verified email.', Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }

        return $this->baseHandler->onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of performing additional checks when user authenticates, Symfony uses **User Checkers**. I would prefer to use that.

There is a short article in the Symfony documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html